# Python - Using if statement, + while condition | Print integers, break when having digits

Tags: python, if-statement

**Question:** 
Write a program to accept integer inputs until the user inputs a non‐integer. Then, the program prints the summation of the inputted numbers.

**My code:**

```
Total = 0
Count = 0
while True:
    n = input ('Enter integers')

    if (n.isdigit() == True):
        print (n)
    else:
        break
    n = int(n)    
    total = total + n
    count = count + 1
    sum = sum(total)
```

I could run the integers, but it fails to break when digits are typed... Anyone knows why? Also I am expecting the sum function to work but it couldn't add together the integers I input.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but you can't use `sum` both as the name of your running-total variable *and* the name of the built-in function.

Comment: what is the exact message/error that you get? Note that your variable names here seem to be inconsistent, `Total` and `total`

Comment: Keep the code in the question as text; don't link to an image of your editor/ide/whatever.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I didn't get an error. I just didn't get the result I need..
Oh thanks, should use capitalized "T"

Comment: One of many small issues: [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: How about summation? 
Do I change it to any variable say 
d = sum(Total)
print (d)

Comment: @EricPetersen, int(n) would raise an exception for non-integers

Comment: "but it fails to break when digits are typed" not sure what you mean, your code breaks when something else is typed, not if digits are typed.

Comment: maybe first ignore my code. 
If you guys need to tackle this question, how will you write the code?

Comment: @Don Ok, Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the sum line and it works fine:

```
total = 0
count = 0
while True:
    n = input('Enter integers')
    if n.isdigit():
        print(n)
    else:
        break
    total += n
    count += 1
print(total)
```

Comment: == True not required.

Comment: Good one, simplified it.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier! But I still couldn't get the summation going..
When I input 3,4,5, supposed I wanna receive 12 as the output. Not sure where exactly goes wrong.
It could just run the integers I type

Comment: it would be nice to explain to the op why their code is failing in the first place (which probably has to do with overwriting the built-in `sum`)

Comment: @ChingLongLEE you have indentation error, while true and then only input statement is working rest of your code is not accessible by python

Comment: @njzk2 I don't think the code ever reached matching the built-in sum - sum(total) would always fail in the original code with TypeError - int object is not iterable. But I could be wrong. OP, if you stop your session, start a new one and run this code, it should definitely work and output 12 for 3-4-5.

Comment: @oldxavier good point, I assumed sum would accept a single value, but it doesn't, and it does throw a TypeError

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
count = 0
while True:
    print('Enter integers')
    n = input ()
    if (n.isdigit() == True):
        print (n)
        n = int(n)    
        total = total + n
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print('The total is ' + str(total))
        print('You put ' + str(count) + ' numbers')
        break
```

Comment: Thanks @Gutemberg 
But still not sure why the summation still couldn't be achieved LOL
again, I am expecting a 7 when I input 3 & 4

Answer (score 0):

By delegating the input process to an iterative function you will be able to use the sum() function directly to obtain the total:

```
def inputIntegers():
    while True:
        result = input("Enter integers: ")
        if not result.isdigit(): break
        yield int(result)

print("total:",sum(inputIntegers()))


Enter integers: 3
Enter integers: 25
Enter integers: 6
Enter integers: 4
Enter integers: 
total: 38
```